# Email will not send to certain email addresses

Tags: centos, sendmail

I setup a centos server to host a website.

Currently the website works fine. Only issue im getting is with mail. Sendmail to be precise.

When magento sends out its order emails it should send one to the client, one to the seller and one to the dev email account.

Currently it does the client and dev. Both emails are different urls. But the seller is the same email address as the website lets call it example.com.

I when send them email via terminal it will go to the spool and not leave the server to the mx records. It should end up in the gmail account.

The Dev email is hosted on gmail as well but under a different email address call it dev.com.

I'm 100% sure its not a email client issue but something to do with the domain name being the same. Like its routing the email to localhost and not trying to leave the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a mail setting in sendmail.

I fixed it by moving to postfix.